What phrase can I use to describe an "upper bound" of a 2D area?
I would like to describe a 2D rectangular region A that completely overlaps another 2D rectangular region B.
For instance, A could be described by a rectangle in within coordinates (1, 3) and (6, 7) if region B is the rectangular region within (2, 5) and (4, 6): Region B falls completely within region A.
Using the phrase "upper bound" doesn't seem quite right because this typically refers to a number: A certain value cannot exceed an upper bound.
What is the term for a region? ie, this region B cannot exceed this "upper bound" A?

Hello, user534017. This belongs on Mathematics SE. You should ask it there as it's somewhat technical.

probably helpful - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle

If you're posting on a language site and satisfied with non-technical language, what's wrong with "rectangle B is inside A?"

... and a bit more involved description that will help you with how this is talked about - https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm

B is constrained by A.

B is fully included in A.

A diagram would help.

You could say B is a superset of A. Or that B contains A. Or that B superscribes A. Any of these can be modified with "strictly" to mean that A is not equal to B. More precisely B is a disjoint union of A and another non-empty set C.

In the last sentence, did you mean to write "disjoint union" instead?

Yes actually. Since a non-trivial set could still be a subset of A, so A union C could still be A.

Thanks for editing. Since some nonempty sets aren't non-null (not every null set is empty), now I'm wondering whether your edit should've gone for 'nonempty' or 'non-null', haha.

Right again. Set theory is rusty. I leapt at the answer because a wild mathematics question appeared.

"Upper bound" doesn't work because, as you say, it has a strong numerical connotation inappropriate here, but there are so many ways of saying this kind of thing.
Options more likely in a mathematical text:

B is a subset of A; A is a superset of B
B is contained in A; A contains B
B is embedded in A

General options that come to mind (some a little more flowery than would normally be appropriate for this context):

A envelopes B
A swallows B
A covers B
A dominates B
A surrounds B

B is immersed in A
B is included in A
B lies under A
B is subsumed by A

Other things like "A ensnares B" or "A captures B" would be fun but are getting a bit too weak and whimsical.

I agree with all the other options (how about adding "B is inside A"), but "B lies under A"??

@ryang I imagine them vertically separated slightly and then lowered, B underneath A and 'under'/weaker than it. It feels fair to me, if a little unusual, to say B lies under the image of A
